# How to implicitly return object from arrow function?

Tags: ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I swa this arrow function in a [Redux example](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html):

```
export const addTodo = (text) => {
  return {
    type: 'ADD_TODO',
    id: nextTodoId++,
    text
  }
}
```

I was wondering whether I can get rid of the extra layer of `{ return ...; }`, essentially getting rid of the block?

For illustration, the following two arrow functions are the same:

```
const fn = (a) => a + 1;
const fn = (a) => { return a+1; };
```

and I can strip the `return` from the second, more verbose version.

But when I do the same to the Redux example and strip the return layer, I get an error:

> SyntaxError: repl, unexpected token, expected ; ...

It seems that there is some confusion between the `{}` in the object literal and code blocks. Is there a way to remove this this extra layer of return here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can prevent the confusion by adding extra parentheses like this -

```
export const addTodo = (text) => (
  {
    type: 'ADD_TODO',
    id: nextTodoId++,
    text
  })
```

hope that helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use more explicit `Object.assign` for (arguably) better readability:

```
const addTodo = text => Object.assign({
  type: 'ADD_TODO',
  id: nextTodoId++,
  text
})
```